# Play framework 2 multiple async db operation

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.3

I am doing 2 db queries in my action.

1, load an entity
2, load information once the entity is loaded.

I am trying this action async. I am not sure what is the best way to go about it.

inside a MAP method would the rest of the code in the function treated as async or would that be executed by the calling thread ?

e.g.

```
F.Promise<Period> period  = Period.asyncLoad(periodId);

    return period.map(new F.Function<Period, Result>() {
        @Override
        public Result apply(Period period) throws Throwable {
            if ( period == null ) {
                String error = Messages.get("errors.notAvailable", Messages.get("entity.period"),periodId);
                return notFound(helpers.Json.buildError( error ));
            } else {
                Long id = countryId.isDefined() ? countryId.get():null;
                **List<EntitySummary> counts = Notification.count(period, id );**
                return ok(Json.toJson(counts));
            }
        }});
}
```

As you can see there is a second call to db **List counts = Notification.count(period, id );**

what is the best way to do this ? Should I move this to the Model layer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a some research I think I have found the solution. One needs to use a flatmap on the first promise and chain as many promises as you want with flatmaps and the last promise needs to be dealt with a map to return the final result.

see example from here :

http://www.wenda.io/questions/1616410/how-to-nest-promises-in-play-framework-with-java.html